# MySQL で user@localhost に外部アクセス権を付与

Tags: mysql

MySQL で user@localhost に外部アクセス権を付与するにはどうしたらいいですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「外部アクセス権」というのは localhost 以外から接続可能という意味でしょうか。

MySQLのユーザーの `user@localhost` は `localhost` から接続した `user` という名前のユーザーという意味なので、`localhost` 以外から接続した場合はこのユーザーにはなりません。

`user@クライアントIPアドレス` や `user@%` (任意のクライアント) という異なるユーザーを作成する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます